# How to find the total redundancy in the numerical list

Tags: c#

If I have a list

```
List<int> mylist = new List<int>();
mylist.Add(15);
mylist.Add(15);
mylist.Add(10);
mylist.Add(10);
mylist.Add(10);
```

If you want Count() which is equal to "10"
Give me the number 3

Comment: Your question isn't very clear - what does this have to do with "total redundancy"? I've answered it as if you're asking for "the number of elements which are equal to a particular target number" but it's not clear.

Comment: Jon Skeet I really apologized for that because I actually used to be translated to applications brought you the substance of the problem, and thank you for your interest
Accept the virginal
With my sincere greetings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you *probably* just want to use LINQ:

```
int target = 10; // Or whatever
int count = myList.Count(x => x == target);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function that takes the number and the list, then use LINQ to filter numbers and count:

```
public int countOccurrences(int whichNumber, List<int> myList){
    return myList.Where(x => x == whichNumber).Count();
}
```